# How do I properly define Keys for omniauth providers in Rails 3+

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

I'm installing omniauth services into my Rails 3 site and need to know where to define these keys:

```
provider :twitter,  ENV["TWITTER_KEY"], ENV["TWITTER_SECRET"]
```

Most people make it clear that I can not define it in the initializer for security reasons.  So then where do I define it?

I do not understand this part of developing with Rails.  Please give some specifics and maybe even an example.

Thank You.

Comment: Why not define that inside initializer?  Sure, you should keep you environment preserved from reading by all.  Or you can read credentials from config file, but don't put that file into public repository.

Comment: Right, but HOW do I keep it out of the public repository.

Comment: Just don't add config file with credentials into the public repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I declare it in the initializers (in a separate file, _keys.rb) and check in for the purpose of debugging. Then when I deploy, I can either:

- replace the initializer file manually.
- declare the keys in the production environment with a bash script.

Comment: Right, but HOW do I declare the keys with a bash script?

Comment: what is "man export"?  Is that the command I use? The link you gave me - are those command line commands?  I can not seem to get anything to work.  Could you give me an example?

Comment: This is assuming that you are on linux environment. Open up a terminal window, or ssh into your server, and type "man export" without the quotes.